# Function on the torus $\mathbb{T}^{2}$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Somebody give me this question but I'm not sure if the question is a open problem or not or if this question have solution.

> Consider the torus  $\mathbb{T}^{2}$, and the $\alpha:\mathbb{T}^{2}\to \mathbb{R}^{5}$ function with variables $(u,v)$  such that $\{\alpha_{u},\alpha_{v}\}$ is linearly independent.
> Question: There exists $\alpha:\mathbb{T}^{2}\to \mathbb{R}^{5}$ with $\alpha \in C^{2}$ such that          $\det(\alpha_{u},\alpha_{v},\alpha_{uu},\alpha_{uv},\alpha_{vv})\neq 0$ for each $(u,v)\in \mathbb{T}^{2}$.

1. Is a open problem?
2. Really I try to give some example where the $\det(\alpha_{u},\alpha_{v},\alpha_{uu},\alpha_{uv},\alpha_{vv})= 0$ for some $(u,v)\in \mathbb{T}^{2}$. But I realize that I don't know how define functions in this manifolds. Could somebody give me an example?

Thanks! in advance.

Comment: A function on $T^2$ is equivalent to a function on $\Bbb R^2$ that is periodic in both variables.

Comment: @Didier Thanks.  For instance $\alpha(u,v)= (\cos(\|(u,v)\|), \sin(\|(u,v)\|), \sin(\|(u,v)\|), \cos(\|(u,v)\|), \cos(\|(u,v)\|)$? If my attempt work.  Find the derivative in the usual form or need some chart?

Comment: This is not periodic in $u$ and $v$ separately but in $\|(u,v)\|$. Think of something like $\cos u \sin v$ or $\cos^2 u - \sin (v+12)$, or anything, instead

Comment: Is that supposed to be $\det(\alpha_{u},\alpha_{v},\alpha_{uu},\alpha_{uv},\alpha_{vv})$? And if not, what does $\alpha_{uu}\alpha_{uv}$ mean when $\alpha_{uu}$ and $\alpha_{uv}$ are vectors?

Comment: I don't understand the question @PaulSinclair but $\det(\alpha_{u},\dots, \alpha_{vv})$ means the determinant of matrix which columns are the derivative of the function which have the variables $u,v$. It's that you ask?

Comment: No. **look** at the expression **you** wrote in your post. You have $\alpha_{uu}\alpha_{uv}$ in the middle of it. Was that a typo? Or if not, what do you mean by it?

Comment: Thanks @PaulSinclair I put it in the correct form.

Comment: Thank you. It may seem trivial, but there are times where I've seen what I thought were just typos, only to discover the poster was using a notational convention I hadn't seen before. So I ask instead of just assuming my interpretation was correct. (FYI - the typo was in the post twice - danger of copy-and-paste - and you've only corrected the first one.)

Comment: I suggest finding a map from $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^5$ with the desired property. Then compose that map with $(\cos u, \sin v)$ or $(\cos u,\cos v)$ and seeing the combined map still satisfies the property. The derivatives will be different, but I suspect that will not matter,